# Dynamically Sized Contact

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have things on my web-page that will dynamically change size when I shrink the size of the page. I have currently hard-coded elements to specific spots like such:

```
<img class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 250; right: 0;"
     src="/static/Pictures/16848_REGO_LOGO_nP1.png" height="450" width="450">
<img class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 410; left: 0;"
     src="/static/Pictures/baked_icon.png" height="300" width="300">
```

As well as a video in the center of the page:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" width="550" height="350">
  <source src="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="550" height="350">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fregotrade.com%2Fstatic%2FVideos%2FRego.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
    <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">RegoTrade Video</span>
  </object>
```

When I shrink the page, the image on the right collapses onto the video in the center, and eventually if I shrink it small enough, both images lay on top of the video. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: My full code:

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/Pictures/regoIcon.ico" />
    <style>
    .jumbotron{
    margin-bottom:20px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:10px 0 10px 0;
    }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />

    <title>Rego Trade Signup Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
<div class="jumbotron img-responsive" height:auto style="background:#CCFFFF !important">
  <h1>
   <div style="text-align: center">
  <strong>
    <div style="font-size:79px">
    <span style="color:#38B859">Rego</span><span style="color:#008FAF">Trade</span>
    </div>
  </strong>
    </div>
  </h1>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <h4> Pre-register now, and we'll donate $1 to charity! </h4>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <h5> Full Site Coming Soon... </h5>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 500; left: 0;">

    </div>
    <img class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 250; right: 0;"
     src="/static/Pictures/16848_REGO_LOGO_nP1.png" height="450" width="450">
     <img class="img-responsive" style="position: absolute; top: 410; left: 0;"
     src="/static/Pictures/baked_icon.png" height="300" width="300"> 
    <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 355; left: 0;">
        <h3><strong>A proud partner of Baked Cookies!</strong></h3>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 600; left: 0;">
            <h5><strong>Mention RegoTrade and get 15% off your entire order!</strong></h4>
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 625; left: 0;">
                <h5><strong>(Valid through December 2015)</strong></h4>
            </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 650; left: 0;">
                <h5><strong>(812)-336-2253</strong></h4>
        </div> 
            <div style="text-align: center">
            <strong><label for="email"><font face="verdana" style="color:#008FAF"><div style="font-size:18px">Pre-Register:</div></font></label></strong>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" size="34" placeholder= "email@indiana.edu"/>
            <br>
        <br>
        <div style="font-size:18px">
            <strong><font face="verdana" style="color:#38B859">Charity:</font></strong>
            <select name="charity">
                <option value="Indiana University Dance Marathon">Indiana University Dance Marathon</option>
                <option value="Big Man on Campus">Big Man on Campus</option>
                <option value="Drop the Puck on Cancer">Drop the Puck on Cancer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="alert('Your donation will be counted as soon as the email you have preregistered with is used to make an account. You will be able to make an account very soon!                
            Donations will be made next school year (2016 IDUM and BMOC, and 2017 DPOC.)');"> Sign Up </button>
            </div>
    </form>
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" width="550" height="350">
      <source src="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <source src="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.webm" type="video/webm" />
      <source src="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" width="550" height="350">
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
        <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':[{'url':'http%3A%2F%2Fregotrade.com%2Fstatic%2FVideos%2FRego.mp4','autoPlay':true}]}" />
        <span title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below">RegoTrade Video</span>
      </object>
  </video>
<p>
  <strong>Video didn't load? <a href="http://regotrade.com/static/Videos/Rego.mov">Download Video Here</a></strong>
</p>
<p>
  <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
</p>
    </div>    
    </body>
    <!--
    <div>
        <a href="/login" style="positon: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"><font size="4">Log In</font></a>
        <a href="/signup" style="positon: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 100;"><font size="4">Create Account</font></a>
    </div> -->
```

Comment: Could you formulate a jsfiddle or code snippet?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap to style your site?  I also don't see the closing tag </video>.

Comment: @Franco Yes I am using bootstrap. The </video> is right below the </object>, just missed it in copy paste

Comment: I need to see the complete markup of your HTML page so I will be able to give you some advise. I can now only guess that you are not using the right markup in order to style the video and the images in their own containers.

Comment: @Franco I'm actually not using any CSS at all, it's just HTML and bootstrap. So I currently have no containers -- maybe that is the issue?

Comment: @Franco I added in my whole code into the part on the top. Pardon my poor style, hopefully that helps

Comment: @Logan (for your understanding) you are using css.  Everything in your `style` html attributes `style="position: absolute; top: 250; right: 0;"` (for example) is `inline` css, and you are using some bootstrap classes, which use bootstrap's `stylesheet`

Comment: @EricPhillips Ah ok, good to know :) Thought css was supposed to be in <style> tags in the header, but i suppose that is probably just better code?

Comment: `<style>` tags define `internal` stylesheets.  you can also have `external` and `inline` style.  Inline is considered by many to be bad practice because of _separation of concerns._  You can read about the different ways css is used here.     http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: @EricPhillips Awesome, thanks for the information

Comment: @logan I really would like to help you but I notice that you don't have any know how about the proper markup of an HTML document. Unfortunately this is not the good place to learn that and it will be difficult for me to completely re-write your code.